# How to set range index in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-analysis

Im creating a job-script to use dayli, and trying to tranform a line-sequential txt to a data-line txt.

Ive already reach the index of header lines and also get the 'laborer code' for each header.

```
for line_no, line in enumerate(data):
    if line[0:10] == 'FUNCIONARI':
        code = int(line[11:18])
        # print(line_no)
    else:
        line_no = -1

for line in range(index=line_no, 32, 1):
    line += code
    print(line)
```

Pycharm return that: "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument"

How could I repeat the code gattered upper, to the end of next 32 lines?

Comment: Can you please explain the end-goal you are trying to achieve by this line?
`for line in range(index=line_no, 32, 1):`

Comment: I wish to add the 'code' of header line to end of next 32 lines.

Comment: To answer in simplest way, `range()` does not accept any keyword argument. Refer to the documentation of range once. https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Comment: So wich is the right function to select a range of lines? I've already tryed seek but dont really work.

Comment: `range` produces a `range` object, which is an iterable of `int` objects that come in `range(stop, start, step)` increments, it doesn't take an `index=` key-word argument, and it isn't clear to me what you were expecting that to do...

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
code = 0
for line in data:
    if line[:10] == 'FUNCIONARIO':
        code = line[11:16]
line = code, line
```

Any time line receives the code. So when the code gets new number, its goes down in line till next change.

Comment: That will only get the last matching `line`/`code` combination